# Sprig "Load more" not loading over https

Tags: craft3, https, plugin-sprig

I've recently added an SSL to the site I'm working on, and it seems to have broken my "load more" buttons via [sprig](https://putyourlightson.com/sprig/cookbook#load-more). When I click the button now, I get

> Blocked loading mixed active content “http://mydomainname.net/index.php?p=actions/sprig/components/render&offset=6&sprig%3AsiteId=32200a47f3a91660d5c53896017cd9e51baccf7f69c571407279fa99ecbcffb91&sprig%3Atemplate=0fb8ec651fc53258017209d22d4e19b6143ac209993784d01a06801fd13e9cd6_layouts%2F_blog%2F_loadMore&sprig%3Avariables%5Blimit%5D=15a1fe68dab9e8d01fdd3bc84980fa5d354e5c72f0e00d06e0841462638f363d6”

and

> Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://www.mydomainname.net/index.php?p=actions/sprig/components/render&offset=6&sprig%3AsiteId=32200a47f3a91660d5c53896017cd9e51baccf7f69c571407279fa99ecbcffb91&sprig%3Atemplate=0fb8ec651fc53258017209d22d4e19b6143ac209993784d01a06801fd13e9cd6_layouts%2F_blog%2F_loadMore&sprig%3Avariables%5Blimit%5D=15a1fe68dab9e8d01fdd3bc84980fa5d354e5c72f0e00d06e0841462638f363d6. (Reason: CORS request did not succeed).

errors in my console. I've noticed that the cross origin error is trying to load stuff over **https** but the mixed active content error is trying to load over **http**.

How can I get this working again over **https**?

Here's my sprig code if you need it:

```
{{ sprig('_layouts/_blog/_loadMore', {'limit': 6}) }}
{{ sprig.script }}
```

```
{% set offset = offset ?? 0 %}

{% set entryQuery = craft.entries.section('diggingDeeper').offset(offset).limit(limit) %}
{% set entries = entryQuery.all() %}

{% for entry in entries %}

    ----Entry Stuff----

{% endfor %}

            
{% if entryQuery.count() > offset + entries|length %}
  <button class="orange-button" sprig s-val:offset="{{ offset + limit }}" 
    s-target="this" s-swap="outerHTML">
    <p>Load More</p>
  </button>
{% endif %}
```

**Edit:**
Added the full errors

**Edit 2:**
Here is my .htaccess file that forces https and removes www

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

# send would-be 404 requests to craft
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(favicon\.ico|apple-touch-icon.*\.png)$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.+) index.php?p=$1 [QSA,L]

# Force https
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} mydomainname\.net [NC]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://mydomainname.net/$1 [R,L]

# Remove the www from the URL
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
    
</IfModule>
```

**Edit 3:**
After resolving the "Blocked loading mixed active content" error these are the current errors in the console when the load more button is clicked

> Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://www.mydomainname.net/index.php?p=actions/sprig/components/render&offset=6&sprig%3AsiteId=32200a47f3a91660d5c53896017cd9e51baccf7f69c571407279fa99ecbcffb91&sprig%3Atemplate=0fb8ec651fc53258017209d22d4e19b6143ac209993784d01a06801fd13e9cd6_layouts%2F_blog%2F_loadMore&sprig%3Avariables%5Blimit%5D=15a1fe68dab9e8d01fdd3bc84980fa5d354e5c72f0e00d06e0841462638f363d6. (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing).

> htmx:afterRequest htmx-1.2.1.js:1368:25

> Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://www.mydomainname.net/index.php?p=actions/sprig/components/render&offset=6&sprig%3AsiteId=32200a47f3a91660d5c53896017cd9e51baccf7f69c571407279fa99ecbcffb91&sprig%3Atemplate=0fb8ec651fc53258017209d22d4e19b6143ac209993784d01a06801fd13e9cd6_layouts%2F_blog%2F_loadMore&sprig%3Avariables%5Blimit%5D=15a1fe68dab9e8d01fdd3bc84980fa5d354e5c72f0e00d06e0841462638f363d6. (Reason: CORS request did not succeed).

> htmx:sendError htmx-1.2.1.js:1368:25

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sprig will use whatever your site's base URL is set to, to construct the action URL. Ensure in `Settings → Sites` that the base URL is either set to an absolute path starting with `https://`, or if an alias or environment variable, that it is defined as an absolute path starting with `https://`.

Also be sure to either force the `www` subdomain or force a naked domain. in your example above I see one with and one without `www`.

Comment: Just double checked, the base URL is already set to use https://. Is there some kind of sprig cache or database that is remembering old non-ssl paths that i need to clear? I already tried clearing the caches in craft, and uninstalling/re-installing sprig

Comment: Updated my answer to include forcing the `www` subdomain or a naked domain.

Comment: I am forcing it to remove www in my .htaccess file (I updated my question to include that info). Is there a better way of doing that?

Comment: So I just realized in looking at the forcing www to be removed that it is http not https. I just added the "s" and that got rid of the "Blocked loading mixed active content" error, but I still have the cross origin error.

Comment: Updated question with current errors

Comment: After further investigation, even though I was forcing the removal of `www` though .htaccess, my base URL still had `www` in it. Removing that resolved the issue!